# RESTful in PHP : getting the encoding parameter in a url

Tags: php, rest, encoding

I'm building a `RESTful` API in `PHP`. I'd like to let the user display any result in 3 different encodings (json, xml & rss).

Here is an example of a `GET` request for the user 123456873:

```
 - GET /user/123456873.json -> Json
 - GET /user/123456873.xml -> xml
 - GET /user/123456873.rss -> rss
```

How could I get the encoding parameter (.json/.xml/.rss) included in the URL with PHP?

Comment: What is your server setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**URL rewriting via mod_rewrite in your .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?handler=$1 [L,QSA]

/user/123487364.json -> api.php?handler=user/123487364.json
```

**In api.php :**

```
$request = $_GET['handler']
$encoding = explode(".", $request); -> to get the encoding (array)
$parameters = explode("/", $encoding[0]); -> to get the parameters (array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for rewrite engine. Continue reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

for Apache this could be interesting: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is different on different servers but in general you need to configure it to serve PHP even if the path is not ending with `.php`
This way the PHP application can parse the path and decide what to do with it.

For Apache this can be accomplished by the rewrite module. Google told me you should read this guide: http://www.logon2.com.au/blog/archive/web-design/php-apache-mod-rewrite-tutorial/